# How to prove that $Im(T)$ is not closed?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Related to this question: [Kernel of a bounded linear operator on a normed linear space need not be closed or open?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1346655/kernel-of-a-bounded-linear-operator-on-a-normed-linear-space-need-not-be-closed)

Let $X, Y$ be normed spaces. Define a linear operator $T: X\to Y$. I try to prove that

(1)If T is bounded, then $ker(T)$ is closed.

(2) There are such normed spaces $X$ and $Y$,and $T$ is bounded so that the image of $T$, denoted by $Im(T)$ is not closed.

---

My proof of (1) is as follows. But I am stuck on (2).

Take a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset Ker(T)$. Suppose that $x_n\to x\in X$ as $n\to \infty$ in $X$. Since $T$ is bounded, then there exists some constants so that $\|T\|\le M$. Then
$$
\|Tx_n-Tx\|\le \|T\|\|x_n-x\|\le M\|x_n-x\|
$$

As $n\to \infty$, we have
$$
0\le \|Tx\|=\|Tx_n-Tx\|\to 0
$$

Then $x\in Ker(T)$. Thus $ker(T)$ is closed.

---

**For (2)**, I consider an example of an identical map from $c_{00}$ to $c_0$ equipped with sup norm:
$$
T: c_{00}\to c_0
$$

Since $\|T\{x_k\}\|_\infty\le \|\{x_k\}\|_{\infty}$, then for $x=\{x_k\}$,
$$
\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|\le 1} \|Tx\|\le \|x\|\le 1
$$

Also, the image of $c_{00}$ is just $c_{00}$ which is not closed in $c_0$. Because $c_{00}$ is not complete and by the result "Let $X$ be a Banach space. The linear subspace $Y$ of $X$ is complete iff $Y$ is closed in $X$". So $Im(T)=c_{00}$ is not closed in $c_0$.

Comment: For (2): Do you know of an example of a subspace $Y_0 \subseteq Y$ such that $Y_0$ is not closed?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes. For example, $c_{00}$ is not a closed subspace of $c_0$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Also, does my proof for (1) make sense?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630556/examples-of-bounded-linear-operators-with-range-not-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of (1) looks correct.

For (2) let $X$ be any nonclosed subspace of a normed space $Y$. For instanse, we can pick $Y=\ell^2$ and $X=\ell^2_f$. Then the identity embedding $T$ of $X$ into $Y$ is a linear operator with norm $1$, but the image of $X$ is not closed in $Y$.

Comment: Thank you! Can you also check my example in (2)?

Comment: @Hermi Which example do you mean?

Comment: I just update my answer.

Comment: I consider an example of an identical map from $c_{00}$ to $c_0$ equipped with sup norm:
$$
T: c_{00}\to c_0
$$

Comment: @Hermi As far as I remember, $c_0$ is the space of all sequences convergent to zero endowed the supremum norm and $c_{00}$ is its subspace consisting of sequences which are eventually zero. Then your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes! That is the definition of these two spaces